# Extract file names according to the date the file was saved in R

Tags: r

I have a series of *pdf's* files in a directory called `my_work`:

To take the names of these files I do this:

`infiles <- Sys.glob (" *. pdf ")` It will give me a list of pdf's names, like this:
`infiles`

```
 [1] "adjust-the-output-width-of-r-markdown-html-output.pdf"                          
 [2] "comment-out-text-in-r-markdown-rmd-file.pdf"                                    
 [3] "difference-between-r-markdown-and-r-notebook.pdf"                               
 [4] "how-to-add-new-line-in-markdown-presentation.pdf"                               
 [5] "how-to-add-newpage-in-rmarkdown-in-a-smart-way.pdf"                             
 [6] "how-to-add-table-of-contents-in-rmarkdown.pdf"                                  
 [7] "how-to-change-the-font-color.pdf"                                               
 [8] "how-to-combine-two-rmarkdown-rmd-files-into-a-single-output.pdf"
```

But it does not give me the names according to the time/date I saved.

How can I have `infiles` object arranged by file names according to the date I saved these files in my mywork directoryk?

I need to arrange in seconds / minutes / hour and day.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you the list of files, ordered by the time the file was last modified/saved. This is a dataframe of file information, so if you only want the file names take the `rownames` of this.

```
infiles <- file.info(Sys.glob('*.pdf'))
infiles[order(infiles$mtime),]
```

Comment: Thanks for your time!!